# Verizon Fios double NAT Issues?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, nat, wireless-access-point

Note: I originally posted this on network engineering as I thought that would be the appropriate place since my intention is to gain insight on whether or not the statement given to me holds water from a technical standpoint (and if so why) but I was advised that it should be posted here instead. So uh, now I'm here I guess. (new sorry)

I have minor networking experience and I'm not posting this looking for support to a problem, but rather am just wondering if there's validity to something I was told by a Verizon tech and if so why it's happening.

Here's the important info: I am a Verizon Fios customer. For the last year or so I've had a second (TP-Link) router connected to the Fios router. The TP-Link is acting as an access point; it is in access point mode and is not doing anything related to routing. I added this access point because I noticed Verizon's wifi was incredibly unstable (and just congested from other devices in the house) which didn't work well for some remote desktop gaming related and wireless VR stuff. All devices that connect to the access point are still part of the original router's subnet and appear and act as if they were connected to the Fios router itself. They aren't behind a NAT as far as I can tell. The access point is just behaving as a switch. The access point has DHCP server options however I have them disabled since it's not necessary as the Fios router is handling DHCP.

Recently, as in within the last month or two, my internet has been going down. At first it was random outages that would last maybe a few minutes, and now they last multiple hours (even all day as of yesterday.) We eliminated the Fios router as being the issue as it was replaced and it seems like the problem is happening beyond the router starting at the WAN cable. The first tech that came out replaced the ONT box outside the house however there was no effect. Today, a tech came out and had a look at some stuff and replaced the WAN cable itself (the one between the ONT box and the router) however when he did so he mentioned that the issue is probably being caused by the second access point. He said something along the lines of a double NAT situation causing some sort of conflict that eventually ends up crashing the ONT box.

Now, my understanding is that even with a double NAT situation this shouldn't happen right? Wouldn't the second NAT just stop at the Fios router and never be able to do anything that would affect the WAN connection/ONT box anyway? As of right now the second access point has been disconnected all day just to see if the connection goes down without it and it hasn't gone down so far but I don't know if that's because of the access point or if it's because he replaced the cable or whatever else he did.

At first I was thinking that it just sounds like a stupid reason being thrown out because they couldn't think of anything else and were looking for a scapegoat, but apparently someone online (I don't have the link) had a similar issue/situation. Is this maybe something stupid on Verizon's end or is this a deeper issue that affects more than just Verizon boxes? Has anyone encountered anything similar with Verizon or some other situation?

If this is exclusive to Verizon, are there any Verizon techs who could maybe shed light onto why?

Comment: You wrote "The TP-Link is acting as an access point... The access point has DHCP server options however I have them disabled since it's not necessary as the Fios router is handling DHCP."   That is the way I hook up my wireless here and for sure there is no Double NAT in this.  So I think the Tech's assertion that you have a Double NAT crashing things is incorrect. Easy test: Hook up just to the Verizon modem for several hours and see if it goes dowm.

Comment: @John Right now I have the Verizon router running with the TP-Link disconnected. So far nothing has gone down but I'm not sure if that's because of whatever the tech replaced/messed with or if it's because the access point is actually the cause.

Comment: Thank you. This narrows it down. I suggest you see if there is a firmware update for the TP-Link and do that. Regardless, do a full hardware reset on the TP-Link and set it up again. These two things are also things I do here.

Comment: I'll check if there's an update but out of curiosity would it even be possible for something wrong with the TP-Link to cause an issue that stretches past the Fios router and into the ONT box causing a crash? I feel like that shouldn't be possible right? I could understand if the issue was just in the LAN/stopped at the router but for it to completely kill the WAN connection seems a bit crazy, though it sounded like this is a known issue or something.

Comment: You said you replaced the Ethernet Cables (easily done) and there is only now two inside boxes: Modem (you said it was replaced by Verizon) and the TP-Link. I would try servicing it as described and then consider replacing it (possible hardware defect which is known to happen).

Comment: Aight. By chance do you have any insights into if the double nat thing is a known problem and why it happens if it is (ignoring that there's no double nat here, I just want to know about what he was referring to)

Comment: I have done numerous setups like this (all still working) and there is no Double NAT involved when the boxes are on the same network (same subnet in a small network). You said you just have 1 DHCP Server (check that again). Even where double NAT's occur, they do not crash downstream / upstream boxes in my experience.

Comment: The older mi424 routers definitely had some stability issues, this shouldn't be an issue with the newer VZ routers, and it shouldn't cause issues with double Nat (which you don't have if the AP is on the same subnet as the VZ router) We had unstableness with our fios here, it was the ONT box in the basement, after replacement everything went back to normal. Side note: Verizon regularly updates the firmware in these routers without users knowledge.. (so firmware caveats/bugs can come and go)

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured. It was just such a specific thing for him to say that I assumed maybe there was some known issue, though I already assumed that wasn't my case since I was confident there was no second NAT.

Comment: @ThatGuy Double NAT occurs when running a stateful firewall on a downstream router when any upstream router is running a stateful firewall - all the AP is doing is acting as a bridge for the WiFi signal between clients and the FIOS. Double NAT cannot, and does not, cause upstream WAN routers to crash, regardless of configuration. What it sounds like is a poor WiFi config on the AP - verify your AP is set to actual channels and _NOT_ Auto: **2.4GHz:** `1`, `6`, or `11` @ 40MHz **5GHz:** Highest DFS channel available, with `157` working the best in the US @ 80MHz [160MHz only has 2 DFS channels]

Comment: That is one reason I suggest a hardware reset on this router as a minimum.